# Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php/pear') in /usr/local/lib/php/pear/common.php on line 22

Tags: php, pear, macos-big-sur

I'm using macOS BigSur and trying use local web server apache2. All thing's ok since I get this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PEAR.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php/pear') in /usr/local/lib/php/pear/common.php on line 22
```

Try to fix it:

```
% php --ini                   
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

In php.ini file I have this include line:

```
display_errors = on
error_reporting = -1
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php/pear"
```

AND:

```
% pear config-get php_dir     
/usr/local/lib/php
% pear
Commands:
build                  Build an Extension From C Source
bundle                 Unpacks a Pecl Package
channel-add            Add a Channel
channel-alias          Specify an alias to a channel name
channel-delete         Remove a Channel From the List ...
```

Pear version show:

```
 % pear version
    PEAR Version: 1.10.12
    PHP Version: 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS)
    Zend Engine Version: 3.3.24
    Running on: Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 20.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

In phpInfo file I have in include_path stuff :

```
include_path    .:/usr/local/lib/php/pear   .:/usr/local/lib/php/pear
```

What is the problem? I need you help.

Answer (score 0):

After editing /etc/php.ini file like that:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php/pear"
```

There is now error concerning the first one. Another error occurred :

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class PEAR_Common, because the name is already in use in /usr/local/lib/php/PEAR/Common.php on line 835
```

One solution?